# What will be regex for the given SMS string

Tags: java, android, regex, sms

My string is an SMS which would come in either of the following two formats:

**SMS for a lead:**
You have received 1 lead
**title**:my lead
**lead id**:12345-2365
**alert setting id**:890

**SMS for a reply:**
You have received 1 reply
**title**:my reply
**reply id**:12345-2365
**ad id**:890

Actually, I am parsing the SMS to store the values in the database in the respective fields. I want to using regex for parsing logic. As you can see above the an SMS is differentiated by a lead or a reply and the fields are different depending on them (in bold). My problem is that how do I use regex to differentiate between these two SMS types. For example, if I want to differentiate between lead id and reply id in the SMS string, what would be the regex string?

**Note:** I know there another way called String.split() but the code written based on this is too long and complex. So using regex.

Thanks And Regards 
Sohaib Rahman

Comment: wait a second. Your lead id and reply id look exactly the same.

Comment: that doesn't matter... i want to differentiate between "lead id" and "reply id" strings. :)

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to extract the ID values of the messages and differentiate between the the message types. The code I used is this:

```
    String lead = "You have received 1 lead\ntitle:my lead\nlead id:12345-2365\nalert setting id:890";
    String reply = "You have received 1 reply\ntitle:my reply\nreply id:12345-2365\nad id:890\n";

    Pattern leadPattern = Pattern.compile("lead id:\\s*(\\d{5}-\\d{4})", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher leadMatcher = leadPattern.matcher(lead);
    if (leadMatcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println("Lead: " + leadMatcher.group(1));
    }


    Pattern replyPattern = Pattern.compile("reply id:\\s*(\\d{5}-\\d{4})", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher replyMatcher = replyPattern.matcher(reply);
    if (replyMatcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println("Reply: " + replyMatcher.group(1));
    }

    System.out.println(leadPattern.matcher(reply).find());
    System.out.println(replyPattern.matcher(lead).find());
```

It yielded the following:

```
Lead: 12345-2365
Reply: 1234-2365
false
false
```